# How to install an application using MDT during operating system installation?

Tags: microsoft-office, mdt

How do I install an application such as MS Office while installing an operating system in MDT.

In `DeploymentWorkBench` I created new application and then created a task sequence. I used `custom task sequence`, but it is available for installation alone not during operating installation.

Comment: Hi, I have found the answer to this.

Comment: Then post it as an answer so others might learn from this. Remember: Every post is not only meant to help you but the whole community.